# How to update a Dictionary entry in ClearScript?

Tags: c#, jscript, clearscript

Context: ClearScript, JScript, C#, Windows, Azure

In my ClearScript-enabled projects, I have a `Dictionary<string,object>` that I use for passing data into, around inside and back out of evaluated scripts.

On the C# side I have

```
static Dictionary<string, object> Settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

and then later on

```
JSengine = new JScriptEngine(WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging | WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableJITDebugging);
```

and

```
JSengine.AddHostObject("CSSettings", Settings);
```

On the JScript side I have things like

```
CSSettings.Add("your API key", CSConfig.Retrieve("api.key"));
```

for setting values.

The challenge at the moment is updating a value in the Dictionary. The following works

```
CSSettings.Item("id") = Wfm_AccNumber;
```

it's just that it's non-standard JScript. What's more the JSHint tool that I'm using inside of Notepad++ complains.

I could do a `.Remove()` before the `.Add()`, I suppose but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
CSSettings.Item.set("id", Wfm_AccNumber);
value = CSSettings.Item.get("id"); // or CSSettings.Item("id")
```

This may look a bit clunky, but it's standard JavaScript and should work with all .NET indexers (which aren't always named "Item", and can have more than one parameter).